# Retrieving URLs from href when 'a' is encased within 'strong' using Python 3 / BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having a bit of trouble on this one. Here is an example of the html:

```
    <tr data-row="8">
    <th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abramjo01" data-stat="player">
        <a href="/players/a/abramjo01.html">John Abramovic</a>
    </th>
        <td class="right " data-stat="year_min">1947</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="year_max">1948</td>
        <td class="center " data-stat="pos">F</td>
        <td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="75.0">6-3</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight">195</td>
        <td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19190209">
            <a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=2&amp;day=9">February 9, 1919</a></td>
        <td class="left " data-stat="colleges">
            <a href="/friv/colleges.fcgi?college=salemintl">Salem International University</a></td>
</tr>

<tr data-row="9">
    <th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abrinal01" data-stat="player">
        <strong><a href="/players/a/abrinal01.html">Álex Abrines</a></strong>
    </th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min">2017</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="year_max">2019</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos">G-F</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="78.0">6-6</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="weight">200</td>
    <td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19930801">
        <a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=8&amp;day=1">August 1, 1993</a></td>
    <td class="left iz" data-stat="colleges"></td>
</tr>
```

In the first row, nothing has a 'strong' tag, but the second row has an 'a' tag that is wrapped in 'strong' tags. I want to be able to get only that link. The result would be:

/players/a/abrinal01.html

There are a lot of rows in this table, so I know I would use find all, but not sure how to say:

Get '**href**' Only if **a** tag has **strong** around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
    <tr data-row="8">
    <th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abramjo01" data-stat="player">
        <a href="/players/a/abramjo01.html">John Abramovic</a>
    </th>
        <td class="right " data-stat="year_min">1947</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="year_max">1948</td>
        <td class="center " data-stat="pos">F</td>
        <td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="75.0">6-3</td><td class="right " data-stat="weight">195</td>
        <td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19190209">
            <a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=2&amp;day=9">February 9, 1919</a></td>
        <td class="left " data-stat="colleges">
            <a href="/friv/colleges.fcgi?college=salemintl">Salem International University</a></td>
</tr>

<tr data-row="9">
    <th scope="row" class="left " data-append-csv="abrinal01" data-stat="player">
        <strong><a href="/players/a/abrinal01.html">Álex Abrines</a></strong>
    </th><td class="right " data-stat="year_min">2017</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="year_max">2019</td><td class="center " data-stat="pos">G-F</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="height" csk="78.0">6-6</td>
    <td class="right " data-stat="weight">200</td>
    <td class="left " data-stat="birth_date" csk="19930801">
        <a href="/friv/birthdays.cgi?month=8&amp;day=1">August 1, 1993</a></td>
    <td class="left iz" data-stat="colleges"></td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('strong'):
    for a in item.findAll('a'):
        print(a.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
/players/a/abrinal01.html
```